# Return and assignment in recursive function in python: None type given, expected an int value

Tags: python, recursion

I am fairly new to python but worked with recursion previously. I came across this problem while working with recursive functions.

```
archive = {1: 0}
def engine(base, chain=0):
    if base in archive:
       return archive[base]
    else:
        if base == 1:
             return chain
        elif base % 2 == 0:
            get = engine(base/2)
            meaning = 1 + get
            archive[base] = meaning
        else:
            next = 3 * base + 1
            get = engine(next)
            meaning = 1 + get
            archive[base] = meaning
print archive(13)
```

I worked with [scheme](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/) recently. So, I expected it to work. 
I want the code to evaluate till the case bool(base==1) becomes true and then work it's way up ward making a new entry to the dictionary on each level of recursion.

How can I achieve that? I am just counting the level of recursion until the fore-mentioned condition becomes True with the variable 'chain'.

[Solved]: I missed the return statement in two clauses of if-else statement. The scheme would pass the function itself and the last return statement would do the work but not with python. I understand it now. 
Thanks everyone who responded. It was helpful.

Comment: It is unclear as to what you are asking? Can you please explain your case with input/output examples?

Comment: I wouldn't code this recursively in Python. Scheme mandates the use of tail recursion optimization (which, although this example would need to be rewritten to take advantage of, allows for efficient computation of deeply nested call trees). Python does not have this optimization and will  simply aborts any recursive call around 1000 calls deep.

Comment: Also, where do you initialize and/or modify the value of `chain`?

Answer (score 2):

Your last two elif and else clauses have no return statements and Python returns None by default.

Comment: This really is "writing scheme in python".  No offense intended.  I do this all the time when I switch between languages.

Comment: @saulspatz I know. few initial days are painful. One gets stuck on every little things.